# SetTextureOffset in meter per seconds speed

Tags: unity, c#, shaders

I have this code snippet that faking the tiling offset speed. Now i want to set the speed in terms of meter per seoconds. how to divide or multiply that i get a number which is meter per seconds:

```
public float scrollSpeed = 0.5f;

    Renderer rend;

    void Start()
    {
        rend = GetComponent<Renderer>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        //rend.material.SetTextureOffset("_MainTex", new Vector2(offset, 0));
        //rend.material.SetTextureOffset("_NormalMap", new Vector2(offset, 0));

        float offset = Time.time * scrollSpeed * SpeedSliderController.globalSpeed;
        ChangeDetailTextureOffSet(rend.material, offset, 0f);
    }

    public void ChangeDetailTextureOffSet(Material Mat, float scaleX, float scaleY)
    {
        Mat.SetTextureOffset("_DetailAlbedoMap", new Vector2(scaleX, scaleY));
    }
```

Like how do i move 2 meter per seconds.?

Comment: There is no universal mapping between the UV coordinates of texture space and the meter coordinates of world space. It depends entirely on what mesh you're displaying this texture on, and how it is stretched or scaled in your world. So we'll need that information to be able to help you here.

Comment: It is a rectangular object exported at scale of 1 from 3d studio max.

Comment: That's not enough information to tell us about its UV coordinates. Can you show us the object with measurements in Unity, and its UV unwrap?